# Prevent user from receiving workflow email updates

Tags: email, workflow

I have a workflow rule that sends immediately sends an email update when a record is updated and anytime it's subsequently edited. This rule is to update users that they have been assigned a new client. This is determined by a lookup field being populated, this is the field the rule looks at. Everything works as expected but the problem is that when this goes into production the user gets 400 emails because of all the records looking up to them. Can we prevent this with a setting that will allow them to get set up without being bombarded?

Comment: If he is being assigned to record in mass then i would suggest to use a checkbox field and make that true if batch size is greater than threshold and use that checkbox in workflow before sending email...

Comment: What are the current entry criteria for your Workflow Rule?

Comment: We can't change anything on the rules

Comment: in lightning: setup -> email -> Deliverability -> Access level: "System email only"